# How to keep AlertDialog until button is clicked

Tags: android

I have this code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity.this);
        builder.setMessage("Message")
                .setTitle("Title");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
```

But it shows AlertDialog for second and switches to another activity. How to make it wait for PositiveButton to be clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity.this);
    builder.setMessage("Message")
            .setTitle("Title");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
```